# Why is this fs loop reading the filenames but not their content?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want to do is to output the content of all the files in a folder:

```
  const fs = require('fs')
      , input = process.argv[2]



  fs.readdir(__dirname + `/${input}/`, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }

    files.forEach((file) => {
      console.log(file)

      fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        console.log(data)
      })
    })
  })
```

But I'm puzzled `console.log(file)` do output the file names:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n/bin$ node index4.js folder
test.txt
test2.txt
```

But `console.log(data)` returns `undefined`:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n/bin$ node index4.js folder
undefined
undefined
```

What's happening here?

**EDIT:**

Maybe there's a problem with `__dirname`? This is my project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass full path to your filenames:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
```

And I would recommend you to log errors so you will know next time what is happening wrong:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + `/${input}/` + file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  console.log(data)
})
```